# Making iOS app using Android Studio and LibGDX

Tags: java, android, ios

I want to make an app (not a game) for both Android and iOS. I have used LibGDX to make a game before and I like this because with one Java code it makes the app for both Android and iOS. However, I want to make an app that is not a game for iOS and Android with one Java code. Is my only solution to use the game engine LibGDX to make the app or is there another was I can do this.

I want to use one code in Java on a windows computer to make the app.

Answer (score 2):

Intel has recently introduced INDE Multi-OS Engine early access programm: https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde-multi-os-early-access

It allows to write you app for both Android and iOS in Java. Good technical overview is here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/07/30/multi-os-engine-of-intel-inde-technical-overview

[image]

It let's to create Java applications in Android Studio for both iOS and Android platforms with a possibility to share logic between them.

Also there is a way to develop an app on Windows-host with Mac build server in LAN.

[image]